# Link that allows access to documents without authentication

Tags: access-control

I am testing an app and I found a link in source code that permit me to access a document without authenticating to the application on which that document is present.

The url has a key in the get and it is that key that allows me to access that resource without authenticating

I can classify it as "Broken access control: : unauthenticated access "?

Comment: why not direct object reference?

Comment: Is this desired functionality of the system?  It very well could be exactly what is intended and desired. Being able to generate a link that unauthenticated users can use to access specific resources is a valid use case for some systems.

Comment: in practice, in the source code I found a preconfigured email in which there is a link that, if pressed, allows those who will receive this email to access their (recipient's) profile. then whoever receives it will be able to access the document and access his profile without logging in. furthermore, always in the email, there are also the credentials of the user to whom the email is addressed. with what severity should this be reported? do you consider it an information disclosure?

Comment: @schroeder you are definitely right. This problem falls precisely in this case, thank you very much.